# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities issue

Tags: ios

My problem is:
I have one Xcode7 project with many targets, each target with his own .plist, of course. In that .plist there is the key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities that is required as apple say here
[image]

Now the problem is in some .plist of some targets i must declare this key empty

[image]

if not, when i upload the app, itunes connect get me an error for this key.

In some others i can declare an item for this key, like armv7 or armv6 and all goes well in itunes connet.

[image]

The strange thing is all the targets (and the .plists) are made IN THE SAME WAY

I would understand this.

Sorry for the english and thanks for future answers.

Comment: The `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` is not required in the Info.plist file.

Comment: are you sure rmaddy? why apple says here that is required? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW3

Comment: I don't have the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key and I have no problems at all.

Comment: rmaddy ok, i will try that. But it is not an answer for my question. Why in some i MUST to leave it empty and in anothers no?

Comment: @rmaddy Without UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the plist , is your app approved on Appstore ?

Comment: @BharatJagtap My app has been in the store for 7 years with several updates per year - all without the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the update :-)